# "The tenant for tenant guid X does not exist", for self email account(I'm the only member)

Tags: azure, go, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I would like to read email for my personal account but I'm getting "The tenant for tenant guid X does not exist".

- I created an app using single tenant on https://entra.microsoft.com/
  [image]
- Then I assing it the permissions to email
  [image]
- Then I created a client secret
  [image]
- Then I use this code for getting the token:

  ```
   import(""github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/apps/confidential")
   cred, err := confidential.NewCredFromSecret("{secret value}")
   if err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
       return
   }
   confidentialClient, err := confidential.New("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}", "{client id}", cred)
   if err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
       return
   }
   scopes := []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"}
   result, err := confidentialClient.AcquireTokenSilent(context.TODO(), scopes)
   if err != nil {
       result, err = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByCredential(context.TODO(), scopes)
       if err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
           return
       }
   }
  ```
- I successfully get the token with that code

  ```
  {
       "Account": {
           "AdditionalFields": null
       },
       "IDToken": {
           "RawToken": "",
           "AdditionalFields": null
       },
       "AccessToken": "{token}",
       "ExpiresOn": "2023-12-13T14:57:09.4905758-05:00",
       "GrantedScopes": [
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
       ],
       "DeclinedScopes": null
   }
  ```
- Then I get the user id(I'm the only user):

  ```
   req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", nil)
   if err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
       return
   }
   req.Header.Add("Authorization", "{token}")
   client := http.Client{}
   resp, err := client.Do(req)
   if err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
       return
   }
   body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
   if err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
       return
   }
  ```
- however when I try to get the emails:

  ```
       req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages", nil)
       if err != nil {
           log.Println(err)
           return
       }
       req.Header.Add("Authorization", "{token}")
       client := http.Client{}
       resp, err := client.Do(req)
       if err != nil {
           log.Println(err)
           return
       }
       body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
       if err != nil {
           log.Println(err)
           return
       }
  ```

I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
        "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '0a6ac917-332a-4f47-881e-0b35fb1b2ab5' does not exist.",
        "innerError": {
            "oAuthEventOperationId": "c096c5c9-e743-4daa-9a97-d14d915e9842",
            "oAuthEventcV": "N0nHeUJm9gwnrFZefuEA4w.1.1",
            "errorUrl": "https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant",
            "requestId": "c0272999-9743-44ee-98b5-947acc52e7d8",
            "date": "2023-12-13T19:11:22"
        }
    }
}
```

Id `0a6ac917-332a-4f47-881e-0b35fb1b2ab5` on the error is the tenand id

Comment: Do you have office 365 license?

Comment: yes, I bought the family plan about 2 weeks ago

Comment: but why is it required anyway? I've used gmail for reading email and I didn't have to pay anything

Comment: Is the license assigned to the user

Comment: ok, but I already bought it, the family plan $10/month

Comment: I'm using the same account as when I bought the subscription plan

Comment: If you are trying to read emails of **personal Outlook** account, you need create application with account type as _Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)_

Comment: Could you sign into [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) once with your personal Outlook account and check whether you are getting emails with this query or not `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`

Comment: @Sridevi yes I'm getting emails on the graph explorer, I'll try to change the application type

Comment: You need to switch to **delegated** flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow while generating access token.

Comment: I just created a new application type with account **type as Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) ** but still the same error, I now it doesn't work the endpoint /users even having the same permissions as the application I created first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256268/discussion-between-sridevi-and-john-balvin-arias).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To read the mails of **personal** Outlook account, you need to switch to **delegated** flow like interactive flow or authorization code flow for generating access token and call `/me/messages` endpoint.

Register **multi-tenant** application with account type as "*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)*":

[image]

Make sure to enable **public client** option if you are using interactive flow for generating token:

[image]

Now, add **`Mail.Read`** or **`Mail.ReadWrite`** permission of **Delegated** type in your app registration based on your need:

[image]

To generate **access token** using interactive flow, you can refer this sample Go code and later use it for calling `/me/messages` endpoint:

```golang
package public_test

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/apps/public"
)

func Example() {
    client, err := public.New("client_id", public.WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"))
    if err != nil {
    }

    var result public.AuthResult
    scopes := []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"}

    accounts, err := client.Accounts(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }
    if len(accounts) > 0 {
        result, err = client.AcquireTokenSilent(context.TODO(), scopes, public.WithSilentAccount(accounts[0]))
    }
    if err != nil || len(accounts) == 0 {
        result, err = client.AcquireTokenInteractive(context.TODO(), scopes)
        if err != nil {
        }
    }
    _ = result.Account
    _ = result.AccessToken
}
```

You can also sign into **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** with that account and run below query for getting emails:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/apps/public/example_test.go at main · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/blob/main/apps/public/example_test.go)