# Can we create event in user's calendar with application permissions?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on a project where I need to create events in user's Outlook calendars. The requirement is that job inspection dates should be added to the calendar of relevant users. Additionally, users should have the ability to manually create events on their calendars.

After some research, I've identified two possible approaches for achieving this functionality. Given these two approaches, I am unsure which one will work for my requirements. Additionally, I have questions for both:

**1. Delegated permissions:**

With this approach, I would utilise the delegated authentication flow, requiring the use of a user's access token to create events in their calendar.

However, I've noticed that these tokens have a relatively short expiration time, usually less than a day. Managing tokens for all users seems impractical.

So, I realise we may need to go with Application permissions.

**2. Application permissions:**

Having only application's access token managing it will be practicle.

I have app access token with this end point. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

But when I try to create event with [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$%7BuserId%7D/events)

I am getting error as below:

```
response: {
  status: 401,
  statusText: 'Unauthorized',
  data: {
    error: {
      code: 'OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound',
      message: "The tenant for tenant guid 'f8cdef31-xxxxx-5f571e91255a' does not exist.",
      innerError: {
        oAuthEventOperationId: 'e3f0be2e-xxxxx-a3cabb87741d',
        oAuthEventcV: 'CNUKxxoGwp3Jr9+kMI/pZw.1.1.1',
        errorUrl: 'https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant',
        requestId: '446a24c5-xxxxx-f592fcef453c',
        date: '2024-03-15T05:16:08',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I am open to any insights, recommendations or clarifications. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we create event in user's calendar with application permissions?

**Yes**, you can create event in user's calendar with application permission.

Create a **Microsoft Entra application** and grant **`Calendars.ReadWrite`** application permission:

[image]

Generated **access token** via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

By using the above access token, **I am able to create calendar event for the user** successfully:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/calendars/CalendarID/events

Content-type: application/json

{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2024-03-15T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2024-03-15T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"xxx.com",
        "name": "xxx"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "transactionId":"xxx"
}
```

[image]

The error ***"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound"*** usually occurs if you are trying to create event for the Microsoft Personal account and making use of Client credential flow to generate token and calling **`users/UserID/calendars/CalendarID/events`** endpoint .

- If you are trying to create event for the Microsoft Personal account, then you need to make use of delegated flow to generate token and call **`/me/calendars/CalendarId/events`** endpoint. Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657118/the-tenant-for-tenant-guid-x-does-not-exist-for-self-email-accountim-the-on) by *Sridevi*.
- Call **organizations/common** endpoint to generate token if you are calling other tenant users.
- *If still the issue persists*, make sure the user has office 365 license.

**To increase the access token lifetime**, you can refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78066329/from-okta-auth0-how-can-i-increase-the-azure-ad-token-validity) by me

**Reference:**

[Create event - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Can you please elaborate, What do you mean by "Microsoft Personal account" ?
Thank you so much for your answer :)

Comment: Check this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/what-s-the-difference-between-a-personal-microsoft-account-and-a/ba-p/2241897

Comment: Does this mean with client credentials flow, I can only create event's in account within my organisation (like school or company) ?

Comment: Yes you are right, if you are trying to create events for Microsoft Personal account then you need to make use of delegated flow to generate token and call /me/calendars/CalendarId/events endpoint and using common endpoint to generate the token

Comment: And can I increase token lifetime in delegated flow ?

Comment: Yes you can increase the token lifetime by setting the  "isOrganizationDefault": true

Comment: @Rukmini Thank you so much, You explain everything very clearly. I was confused for days.

Comment: But if it multitenant application then check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143369/increase-access-token-lifetime-in-azure-ad

Comment: I want to allow users to use their personal account. Do we need multi tenant application ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257179/discussion-between-rukmini-and-nikhil-mandaliya).